# How to change the outputted XML from a recursive function in XQuery?

Tags: xml, recursion, xquery

I'm trying to recursively generate a XML document of countries that borders each other in the mondial database. The document should say how many borders you would have to cross to get to the country and the total amount of countries crossed.

The XML should look like this:

```
    <from_swe_cross>
        <cross num="1" sum="2">
            <country>Finland</country>
            <country>Norway</country>
        </cross>
        <cross num="2" sum="3">
            <country>Russia</country>
        </cross>
```

I know how to generate a list of countries that you can go to but not how to format it correctly and know how many border crosses have been made or the total amount of countries crossed.

My code now is:

```
declare function local:crossing($stack, $seen, $level, $sum) {
  if(empty($stack)) then $seen
  else (
    let $country := $stack[1]
    let $neighbors :=
        for $code in $country/border/@country[not(. = $seen/@car_code)]
        return $country/../country[@car_code = $code]
    return local:crossing(($neighbors, $stack[position() > 1]), ($seen, $neighbors), $level + 1, $sum + count($neighbors))
  )
};

<from_swe_cross>{
  local:crossing(db:open('mondial')//country[@car_code = 'S'], db:open('mondial')//country[@car_code = 'S'], 1, 0)/name
}
</from_swe_cross>
```

But this only lists all the countries that you can cross to, like this:

```
<from_swe_cross>
  <name>Albania</name>
  <name>Greece</name>
  <name>Macedonia</name>
  <name>Serbia</name>
  <name>Montenegro</name>
  ...
</from_swe_cross>
```

How do I generate the right XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use an accumulating parameter in which you gather the result sequence, starting with an empty sequence:

```
declare function local:crossing($stack, $seen, $level, $sum, $out) {
  if(empty($stack)) then $out
  else (
    let $country := $stack[1]
    let $neighbors :=
        for $code in $country/border/@country[not(. = $seen/@car_code)]
        return $country/../country[@car_code = $code]
    let $sum := $sum + count($neighbors)
    return local:crossing(
      ($neighbors, $stack[position() > 1]),
      ($seen, $neighbors),
      $level + 1,
      $sum,
      ($out, <cross num="{$level}" sum="{$sum}">{$neighbors/name}</cross>)
    )
  )
};
<from_swe_cross>{
  local:crossing(
    db:open('mondial')//country[@car_code = 'S'],
    db:open('mondial')//country[@car_code = 'S'],
    1, 0, ()
  )
}
</from_swe_cross>
```

The result looks just like you show above:

```
<from_swe_cross>
  <cross num="1" sum="2">
    <name>Finland</name>
    <name>Norway</name>
  </cross>
  <cross num="2" sum="3">
    <name>Russia</name>
  </cross>
  <cross num="3" sum="15">
    <name>Belarus</name>
    <name>Latvia</name>
    <name>Lithuania</name>
    <name>Poland</name>
    <name>Ukraine</name>
    <name>Estonia</name>
    <name>China</name>
    ...
```

Steps not finding new destinations show up as empty `cross` elements. If you want you can suppress those.

```
  ...
  <cross num="4" sum="15"/>
  <cross num="5" sum="15"/>
  <cross num="6" sum="15"/>
  <cross num="7" sum="18">
    <name>Czech Republic</name>
    <name>Germany</name>
    <name>Slovakia</name>
  </cross>
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for, but how can i suppress the empty cross elements?

Comment: Just replace `($out, <cross num="{$level}" sum="{$sum}">{$neighbors/name}</cross>)` with `if(empty($neighbors)) then $out else ($out, <cross num="{$level}" sum="{$sum}">{$neighbors/name}</cross>)`.